# Use ImageResizer with view precompilation in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404, imageresizer

I'm using the [ImageResizer library](https://imageresizing.net) in my ASP.NET MVC website. I tried to turn on view precompilation to speed up first page load time and the image resizer stopped working. I get the following 404 message when trying to access a resized image:

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

In the debug output (shown below) from ImageResizer it says "(Warning): Precompilation is enabled. Image providers may not work as expected."

Is there any way to get them working together?

The troubleshooting guide says a file not found error could be because "You (a) aren't specifying a command string, (b) have Precompilation enabled, and (c) are using an image provider. This is caused by a long-standing bug in the .NET framework." What is a command string? If I specify a command string will it work? If so, how do I do that?

Debug Output:

```
Image resizer diagnostic sheet      3/2/2017 3:31:20 PM

2 Issues detected:

(Warning):  To potentially see additional errors here, perform an image resize request.


(Warning):  Precompilation is enabled. Image providers may not work as expected.



You are using plugins from the Performance Edition: DiskCache (Performance Edition), AzureReader2Plugin (Performance Edition)

Registered plugins:

ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.ClientCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Diagnostic
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.SizeLimiting
ImageResizer.Plugins.MvcRoutingShim.MvcRoutingShimPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.AzureReader2.AzureReader2Plugin

Configuration:

<resizer>
<clientcache minutes="1440" />
<sizelimits imageWidth="0" imageHeight="0" totalWidth="3200" totalHeight="5000" totalBehavior="throwexception" />
<diagnostics enableFor="allhosts" />
<plugins>
<add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
<add name="DiskCache" />
<add name="AzureReader2" connectionString="[redacted]" endpoint="[redacted]" lazyExistenceChceck="True" prefix="~/assets/" />
</plugins>
</resizer>


Accepted querystring keys:

quality, format, thumbnail, maxwidth, maxheight, width, height, w, h, scale, stretch, crop, cropxunits, cropyunits, page, bgcolor, rotate, flip, sourceFlip, sFlip, sRotate, borderWidth, borderColor, paddingWidth, paddingColor, ignoreicc, frame, useresizingpipeline, cache, process, margin, anchor, dpi, mode, zoom, 

Accepted file extensions:

bmp, gif, exif, png, tif, tiff, tff, jpg, jpeg, jpe, jif, jfif, jfi, 

Environment information:

Running Microsoft-IIS/8.0 on Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0 and CLR 4.0.30319.42000
Trust level: Unrestricted
OS bitness: x86 !! Warning, running as 32-bit on a 64-bit OS(AMD64). This will limit ram usage !!
Executing assembly: D:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
IntegratedPipeline: True

...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Pre-compilation breaks all VirtualPathProviders. We've done various mitigations, but you cut off the ImageResizer version number, so I can't really help much there.

If you switch to the Async HttpModule you may have more luck.

Replace `type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule"/>` with `type="ImageResizer.AsyncInterceptModule"/>` in Web.config.

Comment: Okay, thanks Nathanael. Are there any gotchas I need to be aware of when using the AsyncInterceptModule? What version number is that available in?

Comment: Not really. 4.x